# Multiple AuthProvider Servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I am having some issue to make work 2 auth provider at the same time for servicestack. 
I am using the : **JWT Tokens - Allowing users to authenticate with JWT Tokens** I am my users get authenticate fine.

Still Now I would like to use the **API Keys - Allowing users to authenticate with API Keys** for a few external 3rd Parties user access.

Still when I Configure both my users allready authenticate by JWT Tokens doesnt work anymore.

Here is my configuration AuthProvider configuration :

```
        IAuthProvider[] providers = new IAuthProvider[]
        {
            new JwtAuthProviderReader(this.AppSettings)
            {
                HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
                PrivateKeyXml = this.AppSettings.GetString("TokenPrivateKeyXml"),
                PublicKeyXml = this.AppSettings.GetString("TokenPublicKeyXml"),
                RequireSecureConnection = this.AppSettings.Get<bool>("TokenUseHttps"),
                EncryptPayload = this.AppSettings.Get<bool>("TokenEncryptPayload"),
                PopulateSessionFilter = (session, obj, req) =>
                {
                    ApplicationUserSession customSession = session as ApplicationUserSession;
                    if (customSession != null)
                    {
                        customSession.TimeZoneName = obj["TimeZoneName"];
                        customSession.Type =  (FbEnums.UserType) (obj["UserType"].ToInt());
                        if (Guid.TryParse(obj["RefIdGuid"], out Guid result))
                        {
                            customSession.RefIdGuid = result;
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings)
            {
                RequireSecureConnection = false
            }

        };
```

I am genereting fine the token with JwtAuth. Still It look like servicestack is not accepting my token as a valid session, because now whenever I do :

var session = httpReq.GetSession();

session.IsAuthenticated --> is always FALSE

If my remove **ApiKeyAuthProvider** from the configuration, token from JwtAuth working fine again.

How do I make both provider works together and tell servicestack tham some users will use JwtAuth and others ApiKeyAuth ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a Service that requires Authentication, e.g. has the `[Authenticate]` attribute in order to trigger pre-Authentication for the `IAuthWithRequest` providers like JWT and API Key AuthProviders.